# how to fix pip error when install pakages?

Tags: python, pip, installation

I want to install a package on pip, but I occur this error:

```
C:\Users\Mina>pip install sklearn

Collecting sklearn
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 
'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read 
timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/sklearn/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 
'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read 
timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/sklearn/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 
'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read 
timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/sklearn/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 
'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read 
timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/sklearn/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 
'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read 
timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/sklearn/

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sklearn (from 
versions: )
No matching distribution found for sklearn
```

This error appears to install any packages.

Note: i don't want to install on conda.

I would be very grateful if you guide me.

Best Regards,
Mina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the sourcecode for sklearn package from [sklearn git](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn). Download the appropriate version.

After downloading run `python setup.py install` to install the package

Answer (score 3):

If you check [sklearn](https://pypi.org/project/sklearn/) in pypi it tells you to use [scikit-learn](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/) instead.

Try with: `pip install -U scikit-learn`